# Build the smallest number

Tags: code-golf, number, expression-building

Given a non-empty list of digits 0 though 9, output the smallest number that can be produced by an expression formed by reordering these digits and introducing exponentiation signs `^`, with adjacent digits getting concatenated as multi-digit numbers. Exponentiation is evaluated as right-associative.

For example, `[4, 2, 3, 3]` could become `2^34^3` which evaluates as `2^(34^3)`, but simply writing `2334` is smallest here. You can assume that any array containing a 0 gives a minimum of zero (a special case), or that it's achievable by an expression like `0^rest`, or like `00` for just zeroes.

The input list can be taken as any ordered sequence, but not as an unordered (multi)set.

Test cases:

```
[2,3] => 8 (2^3)
[3,3] => 27 (3^3)
[4,3] => 34 (34)
[1,2,3] => 1 (1^2^3)
[2,2,2] => 16 (2^2^2)
[2,3,2] => 81 (2^3^2) 
[3,0] => 0 (Special, or maybe 0^3)
[0,1,0] => 0 (Special, or maybe 0^10)
```

Shortest code in each language wins. I'll accept an answer just to give the +15 rep without any specific accepting standard.

Comment: "Acception only act as a +15." 
Are you saying that when/if you accept an answer, it will only count as 15 reputation?

Comment: I like the challenge concept, but your text is hard to read and it took me a few tries to understand it.

Comment: @ouflak That means if someone is accept, it only mean he get 15 reputation, I don't claim any accepting standard

Comment: For golfers who might want to write a non-brute-force solution, it looks like the minimal result is the digits concatenated in sorted order, except for smaller values of 0 for any list with a 0, 1 for any list with a 1, and these six values produced from power expressions: `2^2=4, 2^3=8, 2^4=16, 3^3=27, 2^2^2=16, 3^2^2=81`.

Comment: Probably worth including `[2,3,2]` in the examples.

Comment: @xnor I said `Output 0 if 0 is in the input array.` because case `[0,0]` is out of the rule, `0^0` and `00` are both bad

Comment: @l4m2 Ah, I was thinking that would just be `00`. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œε.œJ€.«m}ß
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//8WTzrUuxZNK4oKsLsKrbX3Dn///WzMsNCwzXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5PPbdU7OtnrUdMavUOrc2sPz/@v8z862kjHOFYn2hhMmoBJQx2ImBGQNgLLGYBJE6ioMVA0FgA) or [try it online with added debug-lines](https://tio.run/##bY9NDgFBEEb3TlGxIhkS7CQitrMSW7FoM8VU9F@6qyO2ruAADkBi5wDERVxkzGgSC/v33ldlvFgSlmVzIiVYdCqwYDLag1kBFwgtUlZSRtwG0jZwR5LnITSTx2F0u44bURSOKWpV47dTk8/9ufulU0MaUGRFVdPoOsp4hjoJbNZYDbraSO@XiM8wDxn@F5Y7YLEhvX7fac0Wnf/M1Yu3k4qNqbEgdA42@OKNrqRgRo05KNKkgoq/kofvb/djUpbzXtJPBosX).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ            # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-list
 ε           # Map each permutation to:
  .œ         #  Get all its partitions
    J        #  Join each inner-most list together
     €       #  For each inner list:
      .«     #   Right-reduce it by:
        m    #    Taking the power
         }ß  # After the map: pop and push the flattened minimum
             # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
á Ër!p mDìÃn
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=4SDLciFwIG1E7MNu&input=WzMsMiwyXQ)

Comment: Fails for `[2,2,3]`, which results in 64 instead of 81.

Comment: You don't write \$2{^2} {^3}\$, but \$3^{2^2}\$ is fine

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, `2**3**2=64`

Comment: "and power must go from right to left" -> `2**(3**2) = 512`

Comment: @JonathanAllan, right to left, which doesn't make sense, still gives the same result as the equation is a palindrome. Parentheses aren't mentioned in the spec but that would make the equation read middle to right first.

Comment: It means that the precedence is to be treated as right-most first, i.e. `2**3**2` is to be \$2^{(3^2)}=2^9=512\$.

Comment: @JonathanAllan, still doesn't make any sense to me as to *why* (remember: that mathematical notation stuff doesn't work on phones) but this should now give the results people seem to be expecting.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!*@/€;ḌƊṂ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of digits yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEUtB/1HTWusH@7oOdb1cGfT////o410jHWMYgE)**

#### How?

Checks digital and power-wise evaluations of all permutations even though we only *need* to check forward-sorted-digital, forward-sorted-power-wise, and reverse-sorted-power-wise (and only for `[3,2,2]`), because it's far terser.

Note that there is no need to check any mixture of digital and power-wise evaluations (they can never be strictly smaller than one of the three previously mentioned evaluations)

```
Œ!*@/€;ḌƊṂ - Link: list, L
Œ!         - all permutations (of L) -> P
        Ɗ  - last three links as a monad:
     €     -   for each (p in P):
    /      -     reduce with:
   @       -       using swapped arguments:
  *        -         exponentiation
       Ḍ   -   un-decimal (vectorises across P)
      ;    -   concatenate (these two lists of numbers)
         Ṃ - minimum
```

Comment: Notice that you happen to use `0^1^0^0` on [0,0,0,1] and `0000` on [0,0,0,0]. Unexpected work :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 77 bytes

Based on xnor's observation in the comment section. -12 bytes thanks to Arnauld's idea.

```
method(x,y :=x sort;if(y==list(2,2,3),81,y join()asNumber min(y reduce(**))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/BbsIwEETv@YoRl9rILcXhgEC59dwv4OKSDRgSG9mLmnx9MCoq0IYDc9u32tkZ6/sKiwKrviHe@lK0qktzi@gDL20luqKobWShlVa5VPNp2u@8dUKa@HlsviigSVOHQOVxTWI8lkl9JS5XuZQADsE6rl12wfkwng3jqfqx@YPPifR/nKv3O5NsMkHrfHiJoJaDAVNkrE2kmGWj4lej25vri6FAD1ppNXui7IP4@r4sUvoPMnXEt@UtLKO2e4JxoHJDr@cab/0J)

### Explanation

```
method(x,           // Anonymous method with param x
    y := x sort     // Assign y to sorted x
    if(y == list(2,2,3), // Edge case treatment
        81,              // (It's a kinda weird case that goes right to left)
        ,y join()asNumber// Join the sorted digit-list into a single number.
        min(                // Minimum with:
            y reduce(**)))) // the sorted list reduced by the power function.
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>65</s>  62 bytes

*Fixed thanks to @xnor and @l4m2*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

```javascript
a=>Math.min(x=a.sort().join``,a[0]&&eval(x-223?a.join`**`:81))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9bCoMwEEX/u4p8lYlozENaKdiuoCsQxWC1VWxSVMTdp4pQ1Gbmcw7nzq3lILu8rT69p/SjMGVkZHS9y/5F3pWCMZKk020PmNS6Ulnmypgmx2MxyAZGj3Nxk8vFcbJLyDA2uVadbgrS6CeUEHNXJBijZXwfoRABTwU@7Dix4/gZgbBwwY4TwcQFfxhzV8FzLEPAUlswn0i@ItlpfnBay4t0W4UioNYqW2PI5ip245xOF@/PSAjB5gs)

#### How?

The general case is to look for the minimum of the concatenation of the digits in ascending order and an exponent chain, also in ascending order.

But as noticed by @xnor, there are a few special cases:

- if the list contains a \$0\$, the result is always \$0\$
- for `[3,2,2]`, the minimum value is \$3^{2^2}=81\$

Comment: Be careful with the `[3,2,2]` input

Comment: @xnor Thank you for the notification. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: Fail on [0,0,1]

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Fail on [3,2,2,0,0]. I consider x*a[0] in numbers for min instead

Comment: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1s43sSRDLzczTyO1LDFHI1GvOL@oRENTLys/My9BSytBU6fCNhHCS9Cp0DUyMravsLIw1KnQSow2iNX8n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaYRbaRjpGOsA5TQVODCLkVAkqA0VMF/AA

Comment: @l4m2 Good idea!

Comment: `a=>Math.min(x=a.sort().join'',a[0]&&eval(a.join'**'),x-223?x:81)` thought `a[0]` is a char and find it isn't

Comment: https://tio.run/##hY9bCoJAFIbfW8U8yRmxcS5SElgraAWiOJiWYTOhEu3eFCXUJjzn8f/4L3f5knVaFc9mq/Qla/OglcHxLJsbeRQK3oEkta4awOSuC5UkjgxpZFnZS5bw3nIuTnJQbDs5@AzjNtWq1mVGSn2FHELuiAhjNJzrIuQj4LHAmwUnFhzfIxAGzltwwus47wdjziS4j2UIWGwK5h3JJyTb9QW7N1Sk8ykUATVOmTv6rJ9iduzT6eD7dSSEGFuO@X@kFXFVHoH2Aw

Answer (score 0):

## perl -alp, 83 bytes

```
%_=(22,4,23,8,24,16,33,27,222,16,223,81);$_=join"",sort@F;$_=/0/||/1/?$&:$_{$_}||$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBCsIwEEX3PUUoURRGkplJVZSiK68RXLiolCa03Rmv7jhZvAf//fyax05kE/sdEQQghjNQADwCM9AJSLMOqgfurzb27zRMbQtLmtf7owbnXSkO3c1uLzZ@bPyWYqMIGW5YCQqaukhNalaz8Y03aPwv5XVI0yKH55j/)

Reads a list of white space separated numbers from `STDIN`, writes the answer to `STDOUT`. If the input contains a `0`, output `0`, else, if the input contains a `1`, output a `1`. Else, if it's one of 6 special cases, output the corresponding value. Otherwise, output the sorted input.